# Movie where some children play a game and experience what happens on the board

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was this movie I saw around ten years ago where some children play a board game and then experience whatever happens on the board. There was this one scene I remember in which one child gets trapped inside an elevator.
The movie happens when the parents go out somewhere and the children start playing this board game. The board game ends just before the parents arrive back home.
The children in the movie were kids of around ages 8 or 9.

Comment: Is it jumanji? Or a Ouija board?

Comment: It wasn't either. It a different kind of game. If I remember correctly, the board was like that of Monopoly where instead of plots you had a picture of an incident which occurs to the children in the movie. I am sorry if being vague because I was around 7 when I saw the movie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Was it [Zathura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura:_A_Space_Adventure) ? Here is the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Whfg26yGPx4).

[image: image of the boardgame zathura]

Extract of the wikipedia page (emphasis mine):

> **Brothers Walter and Danny** don't seem to get along with each other, or with their older teen-aged sister, Lisa. While staying at their divorced father's home **while he is away at work and Lisa is asleep**, the boys discover an old clockwork-driven space-themed **board game** called "Zathura" in the basement. The two begin to play the game, the goal to be the first to reach the final space named Zathura. **During each turn, the game provides a card with instructions, but the two quickly realize that the cards affect reality, starting with a meteor shower.** They soon discover that the house is floating on a small rock alongside Saturn.

The two little brothers, as seen in the trailer, can easily be remembered as being **about eight or nine-year-old**.

I think it matches every point of the description, except maybe the elevator part, but as Gnemlock puts it in the comments, there is a scene with a dumbwaiter which could fit.

[image]

Little known fact: Zathura ([the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura)) is the sequel to Jumanji ([the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumanji_(picture_book))).

Comment: Can you please include some details about how this matches the description in the question, and perhaps include, say, a plot summary?

Comment: Given it's set in space with just a floating house I'm struggling to see the possibility of a kid being stuck in an elevator

Comment: @Edlothiad, actually, I remember a scene in Zathura where someone climbs inside a dumbwaiter, which could easily be misremembered as an elevator.

Comment: @Gnemlock That would be very possible.

Comment: @Mithrandir I thought the trailer and the link to the wikipedia page would suffice, but i'll edit and include more details.

Comment: This is the movie I was referring to. Thank you @Kalissar